# Writing php conversation messaging MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating php messaging system based with conversations. And I got a problem.
I have a table with columns: `id`, `to`, `from`, `msgtext`, `timesent`, `viewed`, `deleted`.
I want to select just one conversation between `to` and `from`. Take a notice that if user `to` can write a message to user `from`. 
How to select seperate conversations?

I am trying with this SQL:
SELECT `to`, `from`  FROM `pms` WHERE `to`='$userid' OR `from` = $userid group by `to` ORDER by id desc  LIMIT 50

But this does not work another way. Because if user1 wrote message to user2, and user2 replied to user1, and again if user1 replies and user2 replies, i see as 2 conversations, but it should be as one conversation.

It should be like this: 
User sends a message to some other user. It should show in conversations list That other user's name. 
If user gets a message from another user, he should see his name in the conversation list.

Comment: Please provide your code samples.

Comment: I updated my post :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SELECT `id`, `to`, `from`, `msgtext`, `timesent`, `viewed`, `deleted` FROM table_name
WHERE `to` = 'username_to' AND `from` = 'username_from'
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 0
```

If you understand the concept behind you will realize that you need to play only with OFFSET number to get the next record.

P.S. A shortcut to the LIMIT & OFFSET lines above is:

```
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Also, when you ask something on Stack Overflow you are supposed to show what you have tried, and ask why is not working, instead of simply asking for code.